# Calculate time complexity of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, polynomials

So here is an algorithm that is supposed to return the polynomial value of P(x) of a given polynomial with any given x.

A[] is the coefficient array and P[] the power of x array.

(e.g. x^2 +2*x + 1 would have: A[] = {1,2,1} , P[]= {2,1,0})

Also, recPower() = O(logn)

```
int polynomial(int x, int A[], int P[], int l, int r)
{
    if (r - l == 1)
        return ( A[l] * recPower(x, P[l]) ) + ( A[r] * recPower (x, P[r]) );
    int m = (l + r) / 2;
    return polynomial(x, A, P, l, m) + polynomial(x, A, P, m, r);
}
```

How do I go about calculating this time complexity? I am perplexed due to the if statement. I have no idea what the recurrence relation will be.

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Comment: Before computing the time complexity, are you sure the code is correct? It looks wrong to me -- is `r` inclusive or exclusive? The recursive call at the bottom suggests it's exclusive (since otherwise `m` appears on both the left and right halves of the recursion), but the base case suggests it's inclusive (since otherwise `A[r]` is a mistake).

Comment: It looks like the intention is to compute `sum(A[i]*recPower(x, P[i]) for i = 0...n-1)` where the `A` and `P` arrays are both of length `n`. There's no advantage in "divide and conquer" for this task (at least in the way you're doing it) -- it only increases the amount of work, and will hurt efficiency.

Comment: If the code were correct, one can ignore the recursion and just observe that the total work is `sum(log(P[i]) for i = 0..n-1) + Theta(n)`. Assuming the `P` are descending, and you're ok with an upper bound, you can simplify this to O(n*log(P[0])+n).

Comment: One more comment: you say "recPower() is O(log n)" but what _exactly_ do you mean by this? I assume you mean "recPower(x, n) is O(log n)", but some of the answers assume that you mean "recPower(x, i) is O(log n)" for any i. If the second meaning is correct, what is n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following observation might help: As soon as we have `r = l + 1`, we spend **O(logn)** time and we are done.

My answer requires good understanding of [**Recursion Tree**](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/lec20.html). So proceed wisely.

So our aim is to find : **after how many iterations will we be able to tell that we have r = l + 1?**

Lets find out:

Focusing on `return polynomial(x, A, P, l, m) + polynomial(x, A, P, m, r);`

Let us first consider left function `polynomial(x, A, P, l, m)`. Key thing to note is that `l` , remains constant , in all subsequent left function called recursively.

By left function I mean `polynomial(x, A, P, l, m)` and by right function I mean

`polynomial(x, A, P, m, r)`.

For left function `polynomial(x, A, P, l, m)`, We have:

**First iteration**

```
l = l and r = (l + r)/2
```

**Second iteration**

```
l = l and r = (l + (l + r)/2)/2
```

which means that

```
r = (2l + l + r)/2
```

**Third iteration**

```
l = l and r = (l + (l + (l + r)/2)/2)/2
```

which means that

```
r = (4l + 2l + l + r)/4
```

**Fourth iteration**

```
l = l and r = (l + (l + (l + (l + r)/2)/2)/2)/2
```

which means that

```
r = (8l + 4l + 2l + l + r)/8
```

This means in **nth iteration** we have:

```
r = (l(1 + 2 + 4 + 8 +......2^n-1) + r)/2^n
```

and **terminating condition** is `r = l + 1`

Solving `(l(1 + 2 + 4 + 8 +......2^n-1) + r)/2^n = l + 1`, we get

```
2^n = r - l
```

This means that `n = log(r - l)`. One might say that in all subsequent calls of left function we ignored the other call, that is right function call. The reason is this:

Since in the right function call we `l = m`, where m is already a reduced , as we take the mean, and `r = r`, which is even more averaged this asymptotically wont have any effect on time complexity.

So our **recursion tree will have maximum depth = log(r - l)**. Its true that not all levels will be fully populated, but for the sake of simplicity, we assume this in **asymptotic analysis**. So after reaching a depth of `log(r - l)`, we call function `recPower`, which takes **O(logn)** time. Total nodes (*assuming all levels above are full*) at depth `log(r - l)` is `2^(log(r - l) - 1)`. For a single node , we take **O(logn)** time.

Therefore we have total time = **O( logn*(2^(log(r - l) - 1)) )**.

Answer (score -1):

This might help:

```
T(#terms) = 2T(#terms/2) + a
T(2) = 2logn + b
```

Where a and b are constants, and #terms refer to number of terms in polynomial.
This recurrence relation can be solved using Master's Theorem or using the Recursion tree method.

Comment: if recPower was O(1) then the polynomial would be O(n). Now with the added logn for recPower I am just stuck, I get that something must be done with the T(2) seperately. Can this be solved by replacement? Care to elaborate?